# .NET Web Service - How to see the validation rule in the WSDL file

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, soap, wsdl

I am new to Web Services in .Net and I wanted to know if it's possible to see the validation rules in

the WSDL file of the web Services?

I mean something like this:

```
<xs:minLength value="1" /> <xs:maxLength value="5" />
```

and I want the validation attributes to be generated automatically,  is it possible?

Comment: Yes.  Check out _[WSCFblue](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=wscfblue)_

Comment: thanks @MickyD checking it out, can you add some example of this?

Comment: There is a complete tutorial in that link.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the SingleWSDL link will return a single WSDL file, containing all the schemas in it. Each of the schema elements contains the schema that was previously imported from an external file, such as DataContract.
[image]
Result.
[image]
Reference.
http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/idof/2011/09/17/whats-new-in-wcf-45-a-single-wsdl-file/
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: but where do you see here the validation attributes? I want to see my validation inside this SingleWSDL file? something like my example above